# Let's do some wrestling

Tags: grammar

You say "do jumping jacks", but why can't you say "do some wrestling"?

Is it because of ing form or something else?

For that matter do you say "do some dancing"?

Comment: You can say *let's do some wrestlling, let's so some dancing, let's do some cooking., etc.* It is not the normal way to *invite* someone to participate in some activity, though. You can also ask: *Do ya wanna do some -ing (wrestling/dancing/cooking)?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although those forms (do some wrestling, do some dancing) are correct grammatically, they are unusual phrasings. There may be certain individuals that tend to phrase things like this, or certain locales where it is more common. If you say these things, you will be understood, but you might get a funny look.

There is no verb that specifically means "do jumping jacks". There is a verb that specifically means "do wrestling": 'wrestle'. So we don't generally say "do some wrestling", we just say 'wrestle'. Of course, you can't really wrestle by yourself, so you would say:

> let's wrestle
>   wrestle me
>   wrestle with me
>   wrestle him
>   wrestle with him
>   wrestle her
>   wrestle with her

Jumping jacks are a type of move, in this case a type of exercise. Wrestling is an activity, which consists of all sorts of moves.

One type of wrestling move is a suplex. If me and my buddy were going to perform suplexes for a while (for some reason), I might say "let's do some suplexes".

Other forms of exercise are described like jumping jacks:

> do push-ups
>   do sit-ups
>   do lunges

Other complex activities are described like wrestling:

> let's dance
>   dance with me
>   spar with him
>   exercise with us
>   let's exercise

Comment: Thanks, DCShannon, for all the little examples. These were great for helping understanding.

Comment: Ah...but you do say "let's do some exercise" don't you?

Comment: How about let's do some painting?

Comment: @JoeKim Yeah, you might say "let's do some exercise". As always, there's no such thing as a rule in English. They're all guidelines. "Let's exercise" would be perfectly fine as well. I'm not so sure about "let's do some painting". I would have to research any specific example like that. I don't think anyone says "let's do some wrestling", but maybe.

Comment: @JoeKim Yes, you can say *let's do some painting*. Example: a teacher explains to the class how to paint a particular type of portrait, or in a particular style of painting. After the explanation, the teacher can say with excitement: *Okay, class, Let's do some painting!* This construction can be used with a looooooooooooot of verbs. Probably most dynamic verbs.